# Android- List<object>.clear is not working in my case

Tags: android, list

I have a cart where user adds some products to his cart and if he want to leave from products page I kept an alert dialog saying `your cart will be cleared! if u like it u can proceed` and if user clicks `ok` his cart will be cleared.

Here problem is `mCartList` is my list that is in another activity and alert dialog which I used to clear `mCartList` is in another activity,whenever shopping cart activity on Create method is called the products that were previously added to cart were appearing again after clearing also.

What should I do to clear that list permanently.Here is the piece of code

```
shoppingcart.mCartList.clear();
shoppingcart.mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Could you add the whole adapter ? This code is not enough for us to help you

Comment: could you post some code

Answer (score 0):

First, check the `onCreate()` method you were talking about, if you are adding some elements to the List there. Don't add objects there, just initialize the List and add objects only when some event is triggerd (ex. when user clicks some button or image to add an item to cart). If you're already doing this then try creating new List object

```
shoppingcart.mCartList  = new List<...>();
```

instead of

```
shoppingcart.mCartList.clear();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should provide a method like this inside you activity with list.

```
public void clearCartList(){
    list.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call this method from another activity.

Comment: Provide more code(adapter+activity+ dialog or activity from where you want to clear your list). I suppose you have a problem with getting activity(or list from activity). try to ckeck if its null.